# What WinAPI to use to add virtual share?

Tags: winapi, windows-networking

The question about Windows and shares that leads not to the disk folder but to a device in \GlobalName space. A good example of it is a share created by SQL Server for file stream access. It leads to \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\RsFx0153\\SQL2008R2
Everything shown on that share is a virtual representation: some files, some folders, that do not actually exists on the FS.
How do they do it?

Comment: All file systems are devices in the global namespace.  Presumably RsFx0153 is a virtual file system driver of some kind.

Comment: Harry, I understand, I even write drivers myself. I just can't find how do they do it like this.

Comment: What in particular seems unusual about it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is no user API about that. SQL Server works in conjunction with its own filesystem driver.
So, its is not possible to do, using by only user mode app.